# Pythonic way to access the shifted version of numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What is a pythonic way to access the shifted, either right or left, of a `numpy` array? A clear example:

```
a = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0])
```

Is there away to access:

```
a_shifted_1_left = np.array([2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1.0])
```

from the `numpy` library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`np.roll`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) -

```
np.roll(a,-1) # shifted left
np.roll(a,1) # shifted right
```

Sample run -

```
In [28]: a
Out[28]: array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.])

In [29]: np.roll(a,-1) # shifted left
Out[29]: array([ 2.,  3.,  4.,  1.])

In [30]: np.roll(a,1) # shifted right
Out[30]: array([ 4.,  1.,  2.,  3.])
```

If you want more shifts, just go `np.roll(a,-2)` and `np.roll(a,2)` and so on.